# Does dx in dA=dx*dy represent change, or is it a notation that denotes an infinitesimal arbitrary length? Change vs. an arbitrary physical length

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential, infinitesimals

I'm not sure how to explain this, but I have a gap in my understanding of infinitesimals/differentials. I've so far had calc 1 and 2, and have been taught that dy/dx represents a slope, which represents a change. So, my current understanding is if I had a function dy/dx(x) and plugged in x, I could deduce how much of a change in y I could expect, if I moved a unit x, at that particular x of interest.

Where my understanding falls apart is, I don't see how dx in a slope, which represents change, would also represent "change" in dA=dx*dy. I mean in the classical meaning of the word change. I know we could say "well in the same way delta X is a change in x and represents length", but I don't view it as such.

Not sure if this is related, but here's another thing bothering me, say we have P=dF/dA. Why dF and not only F? I understand dA would represent this infinitesimal area, but what does dF represent then? It's supposed to be a change in F, right? Why do we need a change?

I'd really appreciate someone clearing this up or me, because I'm expected to pass a fluid mechanics test while our uni doesn't even offer a calc 3 course. You can understand my frustration.

Thanks

Comment: [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) would make this a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you take any function $f$ which admits derivative, then you may write:
$$f'(x)\qquad\text{or}\qquad\frac{df}{dx}(x)=\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$$
which are considered equivalent in notation. I guess you have been explained to take a variation $\Delta f$ and $\Delta x$, whose ratio represents a line which passes through the plot of $f$ in (at least) $2$ points. Then you think of derivation as making that line a tangent line on a point $x_{0}$. With 2 variables, say $x$ and $y$, the idea is somewhat the same. If $f(x,y)$ is now a real function in two variables, the plot will be in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ thus it is a sort of surface. In this new setting, the idea of tangent line sounds appealing but not good enough: if you imagine a sphere and a point on its surface, then you realize there are many tangent lines through that point: but only 1 tangent plane. A variation $\Delta x\Delta y$ is now a variation in the area, so we may write $\Delta A=\Delta x\Delta y$. Passing to infinitesimal variations, we would have $d A=dxdy$. Note this little discussion lacks of mathematical rigorousness and it is meant only to help you visualize what's going on.

In terms of notation, $P=\frac{dF}{dA}$ can be written as $P=\frac{d}{dA}F$ if it pleases you more.

Comment: $\frac{dF}{dA}$ does have a precise meaning, it is the Radon-Nikodym derivative. For example in physics, sometimes you will see integrals like $\int r^2dm$ which is the moment of inertia, and $m$ is the mass. If we wanted to compute the moment of inertia of a $2$D object, then we'd have to convert the $dm$ into something actually calculable by $dm =\sigma dA$ where $\sigma$ is the surface mass density. Integrating w.r.t. mass doesn't make sense at all unless we have the Radin-Nikodym theorem to turn it into an integral we can actually compute.

Comment: I see, so it represents a derivation in measure, I wasn't aware of it. Still I wasn't expecting the Radon-Nikodym on a question about calculus 2.

Comment: That makes its (necessary but implicit) inclusion in freshman year physics very amusing!

Comment: Ok, what the hell is Nicotin-Radon derivative? I understood the answer where it explains area and thanks for that, but calculus in physics still doesn't make sense to me. It's as if calculus we are taught in math has almost nothing to do with how it's used in physics. 

Let me clarify. In physics we have $v=\frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}$, which represents speed. To calculate speed, we need the change. And in this sense $v=\frac {\Delta s}{\Delta t}$ and $v=\frac {ds}{dt}$ are similar. BUT on the other hand, we have $P=\frac{F}{A}$, and NOT $P=\frac{\Delta F}{\Delta A}$. So what does dF/dA mean?

Comment: Usually a notation like $dx$ or $dA$ doesn't always stand as a derivation or infinitesimal variation. For instance, when integrating in one variable $dx$ is actually telling you how you are "measuring" the set of integration. In the same way you may integrate in more variables. As the collegue Ninad pointed out, when calculating a moment of inertia the integration through $dm$, the mass, doesn't make any sense at all. But we may "measure" the surface of the moving object, so an integration through $dA$ the area makes much more sense, provided we know how to change variables of integration.

Comment: I see. So, there is a difference between some "static property" dA of an object, as opposed to an "amount of change" dA? Also, you mentioned we can measure the surface of a -moving- object, but in the object required to be moving in the first place, for calculus to recognize it as "change"? Or can it be stationary, and dm/dA/dr/dQ (whatever) still be considered as a "static" property?

Comment: What I mean by that is, I've asked this question elsewhere and got this answer, which made a lot of sense: "One is a static property i.e. the length of a vector, amount of mass, etc.
The other is the amount of change i.e. reduction/increase in the length of a vector by some amount, reduction/increase in mass by some amount, etc."

Comment: Actually the previous one was just an example. To avoid any complicances, take a purely matemathical setting. What do you usually do when you change the integration variable? If at first you have $\int  f(x)dx$ then, when going to $dy$ you obtain $\int f(y)g(y)dy$. Such change means you are changing also the way you are integrating, thus in some sense you changed the way you are measuring the set of integration!